# How to get tkinter gui to update based off of results from code running in another thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I'm currently working on a small project in python 3 using both tkinter and threading in order to make a program that acts in real time along with user input. More specifically, the problem is that I cannot get the tkinter gui to update from a separate thread. I've tried a few methods involving the .set method, .update_idletasks, and launching the thread from a callback, but I cant get it to work at all. Below is a short attempt that launches a thread that should keep increasing the counter after pressing a button in the gui.

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

var = 0
class thread1 (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
   def run(self):
       while True:
           global var
           while True:
               var+=1
               window.update_idletasks()
examplethread = thread1(1, "example", 1)

window = Tk()
text = Label(window, text=var)
button = Button(window, text = "launch thread", command=examplethread.start)
text.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop
```

It doesn't work, instead giving me an error that I know is saying that I cannot use tkinter commands outside of the thread mainloop() is running in. I was wondering if it was possible to get a tkinter gui to update based off of the results of code that's looping in the background as other player input is put in at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

1. `tkinter Labels` use the `textvariable` argument not `text` to set the variable to use.
2. variables to be used with your label was not declared as a `StringVar()`
3. You have to use `.set()` to assign values to your `StringVar()` variables not the normal python assignment.
4. Do your counter with one variable and then set `var` to that variable
5. It seems you were calling the wrong method `start` while you had `run` in your code

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

count=0

class thread1 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter

    def run(self):
        while True:
            global count
            #while True:
            count+=1
            var.set(count)
            window.update_idletasks()
            
            
examplethread = thread1(1, "example", 1)

window = Tk()
var=StringVar()
var.set(0)
text = Label(window, textvariable=var)
button = Button(window, text = "launch thread", command=examplethread.start)
text.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a good solution but just an FYI that `examplethread.run` should be `examplethread.start` the code you provided still runs on the same thread. more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383044/12148778